# How to select the most frequent combination of values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table in a SQL database:

```
Lender  State   Revenue
A       AK      13
A       NJ      20
A       CA      25
B       AK      30
B       NJ      25
C       NJ      20
C       CA      31
D       CA      21
```

I'm looking to create a table with different state combinations and a sum of revenues:

```
State       Revenue    Lender Count
AK, NJ, CA  58         1
AK, NJ      55         1
NJ, CA      51         1
CA          21         1
```

Is this do-able through SQL? If not, what's the best way?

Comment: What is your lender count column supposed to represent?

Comment: Count of lenders who have revenue in a specific state combination. As a different example, lenders A & B may have revenues in and only in (AK, AL). So the output will show AK, AL, revenue, lender count 2.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT LEFT(cs.State, Len(cs.State) - 1) AS State,
       Sum(Revenue)                      AS Revenue,
       1 as Leader_Count
FROM   Yourtable a
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT State + ','
                    FROM   Yourtable B
                    WHERE  a.Lender = b.Lender
                    FOR XML PATH('')) cs (State)
GROUP  BY Lender,
          LEFT(cs.State, Len(cs.State) - 1)
```

Comment: Sorry should've been more clear with the question. There are instances where multiple lenders (say 3) have revenues in the same combination set of states (CA, NJ), for example. In that case the query should return the sum of revenues in (CA, NJ) and count of lenders will be 3.